# Does "a goal very difficult to reach" seem weird grammatically?

Tags: grammaticality

> It's a goal very difficult to reach.

Does the above sentence seem weird to you? It was from a friend of mine. I think it should at least be "It's a goal that is very difficult to reach". But I am not sure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140930/discussion-on-question-by-frey-hong-does-this-sentence-seem-weird-grammatically).

Comment: This is a question and answer site, where questions should be objective. Hence asking users of the site if something seems "weird to them" does not fall into the remit. You could ask if the sentence is grammatically correct, but that would indicate that you are unfamiliar with the meaning of the word grammar, as the sentence certainly is. It is the sense that presumably disturbs you, but you do not explain why. As this is a site for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts" it is clear to me that your question should have been posted to SE English Language Learners.

Comment: @David I disagree, and I think you're being too puritanical ;-) No grammarian would ever close this question. The many reasons why one might assume this sentence might be ungrammatical are quite straightforward, and it is an interesting fact that this sentence is, in fact,  grammatical. It's the pedigree of the question not the language ability of the question asker that is key!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. — I'm not a grammarian, just a list member who is still here and reads the Tour and Help. btw is your moniker a tribute to the late, great, Crossword Puzzler?

Comment: @David Fair enough. I just wanted to defend OP a bit. Re the moniker, yes indeed!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  I remember an answer to one of his clues that went all the way round the puzzle: a quotation from Chesterton — "The name of the girl I forget but the wine was Gevrey Chambertin". Sorely missed, especially at Christmas.